# How hide line in wordpress comment section?

Tags: wordpress

How can I hide the lines: `[You may use these HTML tags and attributes: <a href="" title=""> <abbr title=""> <acronym title=""> <b> <blockquote cite=""> <cite> <code> <del datetime=""> <em> <i> <q cite=""> <strike> <strong>"]`
in wordpress?

[image]

Comment: @PrR3, that link is working for me...

Comment: @Howlin thx man! don't know why i access the link location...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your style sheet should work:

```
#respond form p.form-allowed-tags
{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: @user3279684 No problem, feel free to mark the answer as correct so others who have the same question as you will know how you solved it.